# flutter call group in webrtc and socket io

Tags: flutter, socket.io, webrtc, call, flutter-webrtc

I want to implement a group video call in Flutter. Can you help or give me a sample code? I implemented someone's call, I did this with socket and webRTC

Comment: [This](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App/blob/master/lib/screens/call_page.dart) may help a bit

Comment: Thankful
Can you help with group calling?